How to handle PORT error on render for rails api-only application - NO OPEN PORTS DETECTED during deployment
I am trying to deploy my rails api-only app on render. When I effect changes and push to github, it builds successfully, but does not deploy. The error is  "./bin/rails: Permission denied"
"No open ports detected". What could be possibly wrong?
Error screenshot
Here is my puma.rb file
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

# Specifies the `worker_timeout` threshold that Puma will use to wait before
# terminating a worker in development environments.
#
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3001 }

# port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 10000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
# environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" }

# Specifies the `pidfile` that Puma will use.
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked web server processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 4 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
preload_app!

# Allow puma to be restarted by `bin/rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart


And here is my bin/rails file
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"
require "rails/commands"


My render.build.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

bundle install
# bundle exec rails assets:precompile
# bundle exec rails assets:clean
bundle exec rake db:migrate

my production.rb file
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
 config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present? || ENV['RENDER'].present?

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect" # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = "wss://example.com/cable"
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ "http://example.com", /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Include generic and useful information about system operation, but avoid logging too much
  # information to avoid inadvertent exposure of personally identifiable information (PII).
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "chatterApp_backend_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Don't log any deprecations.
  config.active_support.report_deprecations = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require "syslog/logger"
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new "app-name")

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end


I have tried to set the port in puma.rb. I have tried the both PORTS
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3001 }

# port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 10000 } - render's default PORT

And also tried this
# environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" }

This did not solve the problem

I solved the problem.
Puma.rb was looking for /ruby.exe file in bin folder instead of /ruby.
So I updated the /bin/rails file
From:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"
require "rails/commands"

to:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"
require "rails/commands"

And updated render.build.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

bundle install
chmod +x bin/*
bundle exec rake db:migrate

This worked for me.
